# Axios call blocked due to CORS error despite using encodeURIComponent

Tags: axios, react-admin

In my React-Admin application, I use an axios call to check whether a  form value entered by the user is already in the db:

```
const validateTitleUnique = async (enteredTitle) => {
  const encodedTitle = encodeURIComponent(enteredTitle);
  const resp = await axios(withAuth({ url: `${API_URL}/store/${encodedTitle}` }));
  return resp.data?.length > 0 ? 'Title already exists' : undefined;
};
```

The devtools Network tab still shows **CORS Missing Allow Origin error** on a call to `http://localhost:8080/store/abc/d`.

Then, below that, it shows `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/store/abc%2d. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400.`

I thought using *encodeURIComponent* would prevent that initial error altogether.

Any idea what I'm missing?

I already allow requests from the localhost:3000 origin (where the UI is running) on the API side already, so I don't think this is actually a CORS issue.

Answer (score 2):

CORS basically just compares the origin of the request (domain, scheme, and port) with the allow list and resource-sharing policy specified on the server to determine whether the request should get blocked or not. URI encoding has no effect on CORS. If you're running the React app locally on `http://localhost:3000`, then the API you're calling must allow requests from that origin. How this is done exactly depends on the server-side framework you're using, but this can be easily found as it's a common functionality.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks! I actually already allow requests from that origin on the API side. I went ahead and updated my question to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a curl request to your API and check if the `access-control-allow-origin`, is being set correctly or not, in the response headers.

```
curl -H 'origin: http://localhost:3000' 'http://localhost:8080/store/abc/d' -v
```

A couple of times, it happened so, that, the backend server is returning a `503` or `400`, in such cases, the, `access-control-allow-origin` header was not being set properly. And the browser was flagging, a CORS issue.

It would help, in investigating this better, if you attach a screenshot of the request and response headers for the failed request.

Thanks.